# Azure container registry detail using Azure SDK for Python

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk, azure-ai

As we know that to create a environment in **Azure Machine Learning Workspace** we need Conda dependencies file and base image. In my case you can see.

Build process using this conda file and base image will result into create of Image in **Azure Container Registry** whose url you can see here in portal.

I just want to know how to get Azure container registry url for this environment as azure portal is showing this information dashboard but when I am using **Azure SKD for Python** this is information is missing but all remaining information we are getting, even I have tried to print **dict** of Environment Object but no information is present. Any idea is appreciated.

[image: Azure SDK for Python]
[image: Azure ML Workspace]

Using this code you can print or get the information of particular environment.

```
environment = ml_client.environments.get(name=env_name, version="1")
print(environment)
```

But the information related to Azure Container Registry. I know that code is not implemented by Microsoft as I was going through source code of SDK.
If you have another way of implementation i just want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching a lot around `Azure SDK for Python v2` under `Environment` class but this object does contain any information about registered ACR image.

Then I tried `AzureML SDK` under `Environment` class we can get the ACR image information and here is the code;

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.authentication import AzureCliAuthentication

credential = AzureCliAuthentication()

workspace = Workspace.get(
    name=workspace_name,
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    resource_group=resource_group_name,
    auth=credential)

environment = Environment.get(workspace=workspace, name="longformer", version="1")
details = environment.get_image_details(workspace)
container_repository = details["dockerImage"]["name"]
print(container_repository)
```

This will print you acr image for given `environment name` (for my case longformer) and `environment version` (for my case 1) and output will look like this:

```
azureml/azureml_33d36abd731aa265b0dce682632fc38b
```

[image: Output]

---

I did one Custom Implementation to get `ACR hash` this the same Microsoft is trying to do under the hood I just concise it all credits goes to **Microsoft Team**:

```
def get_image_details(env_name, env_version, subscription_id, resource_group_name, providers, workspace_name, headers):

    cluster_address = "https://centralus.experiments.azureml.net"
    workspace_address = f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/{providers}/workspaces/{workspace_name}"

    environment_url = cluster_address + "/environment/v1.0" + workspace_address + f"/environments/{env_name}/versions/{env_version}" + "/image"

    response = requests.get(environment_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get("dockerImage").get("name")
    else:
        message = "Error getting image details. Code: {}\n: {}".format(response.status_code,import requests
from azureml.core.authentication import AzureCliAuthentication

env_name = "longformer"
env_version = "1"

subscription_id = "c13d3595-ec03-436d-b30a-b21c2b16d804"
resource_group_name = "enlp-rg-ml-lowerenv"
providers = "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices"
workspace_name = "enlp-ml-workspace-lowerenv"response.text)
        raise Exception(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, the Azure ML Python SDK Environment properties does not provide a direct way to get the Azure Container Registry URL for the environment.

However, one possible alternate can be with `azure-containerregistry package`.

You can use this to list all the URLs for a particular container registry.

```py
import asyncio
import os
from azure.containerregistry.aio import ContainerRegistryClient
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential

# Create a new ContainerRegistryClient      
audience = ""
account_url = "<-URL->"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = ContainerRegistryClient(account_url, credential, audience=audience)
async for repository_name in client.list_repository_names():
    print(repository_name)
```

[image]

[image]

For more details you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/quickstart-client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-python).

Comment: Sorry but I not after that. Can you tell me how you will get `environment name` for container repository name? Because ACR will contain more than one Image then how we will figure out which repo belong to a given environment.

Comment: Do you have idea how AML workspace generating `hash` using Base Image and Python Packages?